# Assigning java colors

Tags: java, colors

I'm building an application in Java where different patches of land consist of set of parcels. I want to color different patches with different color. My map presents patches' parcels. However two patches can have parcels in common. In that case I would like to color those parcels with some intermediate color(mix of two patches' colors). As I don't know how many patches are going to be selected I have to assign random colors to those in a loop. Then I have to resolve colors for those intersected parcels. Any idea about best possible way to do this in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For blending the colors, you can get the individual R,G,B values, via either getRed(), getBlue() etc. or getColorComponents(), then take the average for each, then create a new color.  You could also average the HSB values.  You could also play with alpha (transparency), drawing each original color with an alpha of 0.5.  However, at some point all these subtle blendings become difficult for the user to figure out.  Instead, you might want to use some pattern (like stripes) with the original colors.

I've experimented with many ways to pick "good" random colors, and haven't had much success.  The best technique used HSB values.  Lets say you need 5 colors.  Divide 360 degrees by 5 and pick hues "around" the color wheel at those angles.  This works o.k. if you like really bright fully saturated colors.

IMO, consider hard coding at least the "most common" parcel colors into something that looks good.  Pick colors at random as little as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know obvious solution to this problem, but i suppose you can use average rgb components.
For example you have two colors in RGB notation: A(100,0,0) and B(0,100,0). Resulted color will be C(50, 50, 0).

Note: in that case you save invariant "Intersection between two equal colors will be same color"